# python: replace cell values in dataframe column with part of a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

given a column of strings in a dataframe, the following code transforms them
into integers. What I want to do is to just leave the string part without the dot, and whenever
the cell contains a number in string form, I would like to change it to a string called 'number'.
Just to be clear, the cells in this column have the following values:

```
'a. 12','b. 75','23', 'c/a 34', '85', 'a 32', 'b 345'
```

and I want to replace the cell values in this column with the following:

```
'a', 'b', 'number', 'c/a', 'number', 'a' , 'b'
```

How do I do that?

```
l2=['a. 12','b. 75','23', 'c/a 34', '85', 'a 32', 'b 345']
d = {'col1': []}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['col1']=l2

df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace(r'\D', '').astype(str)
print(df)
```

Comment: What I have tried is above. I unfortunately did not know how to change my code.

Answer (score 1):

According to your example which seems to be (1) change numbers only to 'number' and (2) remove trailing dot/space/numbers:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace(r'^[\d\s]+$', 'number', regex=True).str.replace('\.?\s*\d*$', '')
```

output:

```
     col1
0       a
1       b
2  number
3     c/a
4  number
5       a
6       b
```

Comment: thanks, and how do you preserve the original number instead of replacing it with 'number' ?

Comment: The I would remove the first `replace` and either make the space mandatory `\s+` in the second `replace` or add a mandatory something at the beginning, depending on your use case. Give me more details if you need help building this